# java script access to element inside another element

Tags: javascript, html

i want to access a element inside another element .this is the html script

```
<label id="loginbutton" class="uiButton uiButtonConfirm" for="u_0_n">

    <input id="u_0_n" type="submit" tabindex="4" value="Log In"></input>

</label>
```

i actually want to change  type "submit " to type="button"but  input id(u_0_n)  is not unique .it can be changed anytime.but lable id never change.so i want to access loginbutton and then first input tag inside it.

i tried like this;

```
document.getElementById('loginbutton').contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].setAttribute("type","button");
```

but it's not working .any idea how to access element inside another

Comment: You're almost there. just remove the `contentDocument` from your code.

Comment: document.getElementById('loginbutton').getElementsByTagName('input')[0].setAttribute("type","button");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this as :

Your html

```
<label id="loginbutton" class="uiButton uiButtonConfirm" for="u_0_n">

    <input id="u_0_n" type="submit" tabindex="4" value="Log In"></input>

</label>
```

Write JS function as

```
function GetElementInsideContainer(containerID, childID) {
    var elm = document.getElementById(childID);
    var parent = elm ? elm.parentNode : {};
    return (parent.id && parent.id === containerID) ? elm : {};
}
```

then make function call as:

```
var e = GetElementInsideContainer("loginbutton", "u_0_n");
alert(e.id);
```

e is the required element and alert will give its id.

Refer to [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mazzu/VV7Vb/) for same:

**If you don't want to go through id then :**

You should be using a class, or just iterating through the inputs and keeping track of an index.

Try something like this:

```
var div2 = document.getElementById('div2');
for(i = j = 0; i < div2.childNodes.length; i++){
    if(div2.childNodes[i].nodeName == 'INPUT'){
        j++;
        var input = div2.childNodes[i];
        alert('This is edit'+j+': '+input);
    }
}
```

Refer to **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/JR33k/)**

Comment: @madhawa priyashantha,  what happen, is it not the code you needed?

Comment: your code is ok if i know id of the input[0] is exactly "u_0_n".but actually it's changeable.for example next time script may looks like ;
///see the code
<label id="loginbutton" class="uiButton uiButtonConfirm" for="u_0_n">

    <input id="u_0_b" type="submit" tabindex="4" value="Log In"></input>

</label>
//end
i can't ensure that  it's id is always be the same.if i know it's "u_0_n" ,i will access to it via document.getElementById("u_0_n");

Comment: @madhawa priyashantha, plz find my answer updates according to your comment. Hope this can be helpful :)

Comment: tnx .i will check test it

Comment: @madhawa priyashantha, you can refer to above fiddle link for demo

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: (minor change)

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="loginbutton" class="uiButton uiButtonConfirm" for="u_0_n">

<input id="u_0_n" type="submit" tabindex="4" value="Log In"></input>

</label>
<script>
document.getElementById('loginbutton').getElementsByTagName('input')[0].setAttribute("type","button");
</script>
```

Comment: why do you include <script src="jquery.min.js"></script> ??

Comment: Sorry, i was testing in my server, copied accidentally!